# Sync Mercurial repositories with two central servers without connection

Tags: mercurial, synchronization, distributed

I'm new to mercurial and I have problems with the solution we're working to implement in my company. I work in a Lab with a strict security environment and the production Mercurial server is in a isolated network. All people have two computers, one to work in the "real world" and another one to work in the isolated and secure environment.

The problem is that we have other Labs distributed around the world and in some cases we need to work together two or more Labs in a project. Every Lab has a HG server for to manage their own projects locally, but I'm not sure if our method to sync common projects is the best solution. To solve that, we use a "bundle" to send the news changesets from one Lab to another. My question is about how good is this method because the solution is a little bit complicate. The procedure is more or less that way:

- In Lab B, hg pull and update to be sure about the last version in local folder.
  Ask the other about the "hg log", to see what are the last common changeset.
- In Lab A: hg pull and update to be sure about the last version in local folder.
- In Lab A: Make bundle, "hg bundle --base XX project.bundle" (where XX is the last common changeset).
- Send it to Lab B (with a complicated method due the security normative: encrypt files, encrypt drives, secure erases, etc).
- In Lab B: "hg unbundle projectYY.bundle" in the local folder.
- This process creates two heads, that sometimes force you to make merges.
- Once the changesets from Lab A are correctly implemented at Lab B, we need to repeat the process in the opposite direction, to implement the evolution of the project in the Lab B to the Lab A.

Could anyone enlighten me the way to find the best solution to get out of this dilemma?
Anyone have a better solution?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: isolated network - OK, but it will nor answer on question "Can you move to|from secured workplace physical objects?" Clone on USB-stick with two different remotes seems as usable solution

Answer (score 2):

Bundles are the right vehicle for propagating changes without a direct connection. But you can simplify the bundle-building process by modeling communication locally:

- In Lab A, maintain *repoA* (the central repo for local use), as well as *repoB*, which represents the state of the repository in lab B. Lab B has a complementary set-up.

You can use this dual set-up to model the relationship between the labs as if you had a direct connection, but changeset sharing proceeds via bundles instead of push/pull.

- From the perspective of Lab A: Update *repoA* the regular way, but update *repoB* only with bundles that you receive from Lab B and bundles (or changesets) that you are sending to Lab B.

More specifically (again from the perspective of Lab A):

1. In the beginning the repos are synchronized, but as development progresses, changes are committed only to *repoA.*
2. When it's time to bring lab B up to speed, just go to *repoA* and run `hg outgoing path/to/repoB`. You now know what to bundle without having to request and study lab B's logs. In fact, `hg bundle bundlename.bzip repoB` will bundle the right changesets for you.
3. Encrypt and send off your bundle.
4. You can assume that the bundle will be integrated into Lab B's home repo, so update our local *repoB* as well, either by pushing directly or (for assured consistency) by unbundling (importing) the bundle that was mailed off.
5. When lab B receives the bundle, they will import it to their own copy of *repoA*-- it is now updated to the same state as *repoA* in lab A. Lab B can now push or pull changes into their own *repoB*, and merge them (in *repoB*) with their own unshared changesets. This will generate one or more merge changesets, which are handled just like any other check-ins to lab B's *repoB.*

And that's that. When lab B sends a bundle back to lab A, it will use the same process, steps 1 to 5. Everything stays synchronized just like they would if the repositories were directly connected. As always, it pays to synchronize frequently so as to avoid diverging too far and encountering merge conflicts.

In fact you have more than two labs. The approaches to keeping them synchronized are the same as if you had a direct connection: Do you want a "star topology" with a central server that is the only node the other labs communicate with directly? Then each lab only needs a local copy of this server. Do you need lots of bilateral communication before some work is shared with everyone? Then keep a local model of every lab you want to exchange changesets with.

Comment: I need to study that you approach, it seems a good solution for to have the same timeline in everywhere. I think the best is only keep synchronized each repository with the laboratory working on it, not all, so maybe that help me to have a better organized repos. Thanks for your anwer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying-- of course each lab must keep its own up to date with what their developers are doing. But to develop a common body of code, you need to synchronize with at least one other repo (which usually would be a central communications hub).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no direct network communication between the two mercurial repositories, then the method you describe seems like the easiest way to sync those two repositories.

You could probably save a bit on the process boilerplate on getting the new changesets which need bundling, how exactly depends.

For once, you don't need to update your working copy in order to create the bundles; it suffices to just have the repo, you don't need a working copy.

And if you know the date and time of the last sync, you can simply bundle all changesets added since that time, using an appropriate revset, e.g. all revisions since 30th March this year: `hg log -r'date(">2015-03-30")'` Thus you could skip a lengthy manual review process.

If your repository is not too big (thus fits on the media you use for exchange), simply copy it there in its entirety and do a local pulls from that exchange disk to sync, skipping those review processes, too.

Of course you will not be able to avoid making the merges - they are the price you have to pay when several people work on the same thing at the same time and both commit to their own repos.

Comment: "the date and time of the last sync" may be just bookmark

Comment: Bookmarks will prove less reliable in case of a non-linear history and several heads. However you could use the date and time of that bookmark to get a list of all changesets since it was created.

Comment: OK, for non-linear history [remotebranches](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-remotebranches) with `remotebranches()` revset?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it would be a good way to see the real timeline of the commits.